# Fetch all fields from all rows - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I understand this could appear alarming but bear with me.

I need to echo every field in every row in a table.

This is only an example - I have removed the HTML wrapped around it to improve readability.

```
$a = 1;

while ($a <= $count_rows) {
    $query = "SELECT col1, col2 etc.. FROM table WHERE `id`='$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $i = 1; 

    while($i <= $count_fields) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
        echo "$row[$i]";
        $i++;       
    }

    $a++;
    $id = $a;
}
```

This only outputs the first field of every row? Why?

If I echo `$row[2]` I get nothing!

Comment: _Did you know_ that you can retrieve multiple results using a single query?  So using MySQL, you could just have a query of the form `select * from table where id in ( 1,2,3,4,5,6 )`

Comment: Yeah i knew but anyway of doing it dynamically? I don't know how many rows i'm going to have you see

Comment: What is $count_fields?

Comment: @bobobobo how do i accept your revision?

Comment: Oh it's just a suggestion/tip, not an edit.

Comment: Ok, will change in a sec. Cheers... i do need to work on superfluous stuff. My bad it was fthiella that edited it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I echo $row[2] I get nothing!

because it's actually *third* item
and there is some strange code interfering with $i variable

Anyway, to get every column from every row ou need a code like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $index => $value) {
        echo "$index => $value, ";
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Every time he does `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);` he's only echo'ing `$row[1]`

Comment: +1 mysqli_fetch_row($result) instead of MYSQL_NUM Ill give it a try but it appears more logical, tend to shy away from foreach - it doesn't have any adverse affect on html inside the loop does it?

Comment: @bobobobo why? the $i = 1; is in the first loop not the second...?